# bilinear form decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field of $\text{char} \neq 2$. Then if $g: V \times V \to F$ is a bilinear form, and $U \subseteq V$ is a subspace, do we have $V = U + U^\perp$, where $U^\perp = \{x \in V | g(x,U) = 0\}$? Of course, this is the case when $g$ is an inner product. Is it the case for an arbitrary bilinear form?

I don't recall seeing this is any of my linear algebra courses.

EDIT: Ok, so it's not true. Does it hold when $g$ is nondegenerate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general. Take $g$ to be skew-symmetric, say, on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Say, it's matrix in some basis $u,v$ is $\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ -1 & 0}$, and take $U=Span(u)$. Then $U^\perp=U$.

Such decomposition is true if $g$ is symmetric.

Comment: does it work when $g$ is nondegenerate?

Comment: In my example $g$ was nondegenerate.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.

Comment: And when $g$ is symmetric non-degenerate, Gram-Schmidt gives the explicit construction.